# Disable Message "To run this application you must install .net core"

Tags: c#, .net-core

Hello fellow stackoverflow people :)

I am developing an app that test .netcore desktop dependencies on client computers.

First I have checked if the necesary windows updates(win7) are installed followed by a check for the .netcore runtime with a net framework 452 app.

Finally just to be sure i would like to run a .netcore app without UI to make sure everything is fine, it has a custom exit code. But of course I get the message "to run this application you must install .net core" in case runtime is not installed.

My question is, is there a way to hide this message? I want to install everything silently then run a test, there is no need for the Yes/No Dialog redirecting to a website.

Comment: No. Your application can't run without .NET Core installed, so how is it supposed to run and check for the .NET Core Runtime without being able to run? Depending on how you're creating the installer, it may be possible to have the installation wizard install the required .NET Core Runtime. If not, maybe check out [publishing your app as self-contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained)

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough. i will edit it. There is a net452 app that does all the checks, and finally it runs a netcore app that has a specific exit code which lets us know it ran fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is not doable, at least not yet. I will accept this as an answer so the question gets closed.

Our solution was to deploy standalone, avoiding the message totally.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the **MyAppName.runtimeconfig.json** file.   The runtime is probably OK and already installed.  You may be missing other build time config files besides this one.
This file should have been in your build directory.

But  **MyAppName.runtimeconfig.json**  is usually the culprit.

Comment: No, it's not installed, this was the whole point, to handle it for clients that don't have the runtime installed. Since we cannot find a way to hide the message, we will instead deploy standalone and avoid it all together.

Comment: Yes, I once ran into this problem, with the framework ready but something wrong in this json. Now I run into the problem again, with both the framework and json ready. I will be back when it's solved.